# HTML5 Video Error - Internet Explorer 9

Tags: html5-video, internet-explorer-9

I am trying to get a .m4v video to play in IE9 using html5 video tags. When I play the video from a remote location it works fine:

```
<video src="http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270_h264aac.m4v" controls="controls">
</video>
```

But when I want to play it from my server...

```
<video src="Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270_h264aac.m4v" controls="controls">
</video>
```

...it only works in Chrome and not in IE9.

What could cause the video not to play when located on my server?

Many thanks,

Chris

Comment: Is the video in the same location as the HTML?

Comment: Hi Ardman. Yeah, it is in the same directory. The video plays fine in IE9 when I am testing it on my localhost, but not when it is on my server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to needing the server to send the correct `Content-Type` header for the requested video file itself, you should consider using a child `<source>` tag instead of the `src` attribute, eg:

```
<video controls="controls">
<source src="Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270_h264aac.m4v" type='video/x-m4v; codecs="..."'>
</video>
```

That will allow you to specify up-front the actual video type information so the browser can decide whether to even download the file at all.  As well as give you flexibility to offer additional video types later on, if desired.

Answer (score 5):

I have found the problem. IE9 RC was seeing the video as plain/text and not video/m4v so it was not able to play. Chrome and IE8 read the file correctly.

Adding `AddType video/x-m4v .m4v` to my htaccess made sure IE9 RC was able to read it as a video/mp4 file.

Crazy eh?

Comment: Not crazy at all.  The `<video>` tag relies on the server sending the correct `Content-Type` header for the requested video file.  Sounds like your server simply does not have a native registration of the `.m4v` file extension, so it defaulted.

Comment: Ah fair enough. It just seemed strange that Chrome could figure out it was a m4v/video file rather than IE9 RC thinking it was plain/text. Thanks for your comments and answer above. I will bear the <source> tag in mind.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I would have probably wasted several hours w/o every thinking about the Mime Type.

Answer (score 5):

In order for your server to associate the correct MIME types with the application, you will need to include the MIME types into your htaccess file.

Here is an example of several MIME types that you can include within your .htaccess file:

```
#Video MIME Types:
AddType video/m4v .m4v
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```