# HTML 5 video tag: is it possible to set src to a network resource?

Tags: html, html5-video

For an internal website, I'm trying to show an inline video of an avi file on the network.

```
<video class="VideoTagLink" src="file://\\network\path\file.avi" controls="controls"></video>
```

In IE9 I get a red X and Chrome only shows a play button -- is this a supported scenario in HTML 5?

edit:
I have changed my html to this:

```
<video class="VideoTagLink" controls="controls">
<source src="http://localhost:99/Handlers/GetVideo?path=\\network\path\file.avi" type="video/x-msvideo">
</video>
```

and my handler is just:

```
public ActionResult GetVideo(string path)
    {
        return base.File(path, "video/x-msvideo");
    }
```

So I believe i'm sending the right content type. I verified in IIS that *.avi is mapped to video/x-msvideo. If I navigate to that src URL directly in either browser, I get a download prompt for the video file, so I assume that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

See [HTML5 Video Error - Internet Explorer 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006765/html5-video-error-internet-explorer-9). This happens because IE9 cannot determine the content type, and your file server is not sending a Content-Type header.

If you serve the file via HTTP, you can configure your web server to specify the correct content type.