# IE9 not playing MP4 in video tag

Tags: html, video, internet-explorer-9, mp4

I am using a CodeCanyon piece of work - http://codecanyon.net/item/html5-video-gallery-with-live-playlist-/490139 to create a gallery. It all works locally running WAMP, however when I uploaded to a server it doesnt play the MP4 in IE9. I had an issue where the Mime Types were incorrect and ogv/mp4 were returning plain text, but thats been fixed now.

From looking at the network tab in IE9 it loads about 2kb of the file and then stops, I can't understand whats happening (again this works fine on a local server).

Webkit & Gecko play the OGV fine. Safari also plays the video fine.

http://www.guildproperty.co.uk/videos/ is the url.

```
Key Value
Response    HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
ETag    "355802a-1561d8e-4c013c59aa2c0"
Content-Length  22420878
Content-Type    video/mpeg
Last-Modified   Tue, 15 May 2012 14:10:59 GMT
```

Comment: you may check that answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006765/html5-video-error-internet-explorer-9)

Comment: Thanks, however that answer isn't applicable - I've already stated I've fixed the `text/plain` issue, as you can see by `Content-Type    video/mpeg`

Comment: When you are posting link you should also sumup the answer..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Content-Type:` `video/mpeg` is for MPEG-1 video.  For MP4 it should be `video/mp4`.